# Telethon is not sending video as round even if video_note = True

Tags: bots, telegram, telethon

I tried it with different videos and it won't work. :/

In the docs they clearly say I should do:

```
await client.send_file(entity = "chat", file="C:\\Users\fold\to\video.mp4", video_note = True)
```

But it won't work. :/

Answer (score 0):

entity should be the phone number or userid of the recipient.

Answer (score 0):

To make a long story short.
The code explanes itself.
And, of course, your video must be of the appropriate format.

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events

api_id = xxx
api_hash = 'xxx'

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

# send any message to your bot
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def my_event_handler(event):
    
    # the telethon bot can be subscribed to your channel
    if event.message.peer_id.to_dict()['_'] == 'PeerChannel':
        actual_id = event.message.peer_id.to_dict()['channel_id']
    if event.message.peer_id.to_dict()['_'] == 'PeerUser':
        actual_id = event.message.peer_id.to_dict()['user_id']
    
    await client.send_message(actual_id, message = 'Here we go')

    file_path = 'C:/Users/fold/to/video.mp4' # make sure the path exists

    await client.send_file(actual_id, file=file_path, video_note=True)
        
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```